# getting the numeric value of "this Monday" - php

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to display a numeric value of the current week,

in a calendar-like feature that I have on a website I'm working on.

So, the function that I came up with in the end, working, is...

```
echo date("d", strtotime("this Tuesday"));
```

All goes well for most of the days, 
except that, for example, today is Tuesday, the 25th, all week dates display well
since Tuesday to Sunday (25 - 30),
but for Monday it will say 01, because I think it thinks that "this Monday" is the 01 of December, not yesterday. This Monday usually should be the Monday of this week, yesterday (24), but the function when you apply "this Monday" will display the next Monday, because today it's already Tuesday, and yesterday is out of the scope ?

But this is weird, because i'm reffering to "this Monday", Monday of this week. It displays the next Monday. Is that a bug in the date function ?

How do I safely get the values of the days of the week otherwise?

thanks!

Comment: Even in common speech "this" is rather ambiguous. I would never rely on `strtotime`'s automagic keyword recognition for such things and instead do the little bit of time math required "by hand". E.g. `date('w')` to figure out what day of the week it is, then go from there...

Comment: I tested with "last monday" (yesterday), and it shows 24, today it's 25 so all good. But this means that date treats this monday actually next monday, if monday has passed and today is tuesday. Which is lame, because the way it should be thought as function is purely the numeric values of the current days of the week, as a whole scope.

Comment: deceze, yes, but since we got so many functions in PHP regarding date, they should work. I think this monday should not be ambiguous. This monday is definitely not next monday, and last monday should not be yesterday, just because today is tuesday. This monday has passed, but still it's this monday.

Comment: *Let's meet up for coffee to talk about it this Monday.* - So, we should meet yesterday? :P

Comment: true, from that point of view. but I was talking really programmer's point of view, in which "this monday, or this sunday" reffers strictly to this current week

Comment: If you do write "this week", then yes. But just "this" has no more meaning with regards to weekly scope in programming than it does in natural language. In fact, `strtotime` tries to emulate natural language... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strtotime("Monday this week");
```

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php):

> reltext space 'week' | Handles the special format "weekday + last/this/next week". | "Monday next week"

Comment: @AdrianTanase: what do you expect to get (which date), when you will call `Monday this week` on date `2014-11-23` ?

Comment: @Glavić has a point: closely [examine this page](http://gamereplays.org/reference/strtotime.php) to avoid nasty surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with "last Monday" and "next Monday" keywords.

For Example:

```
echo date("d", strtotime("last Monday"));
```

another example...

```
echo date("d", strtotime("next Monday"));
```